# How to send a parameter on the all of request in Restangular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters, restangular

I want to send a parameter as `lang` for all request that use rectangular. Is there any way so I that add this parameter in `app.config` section?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the value in the interceptor, e.g:

```
Restangular.setDefaultRequestParams({lang: "en"});
```

Link: [setdefaultrequestparams](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#setdefaultrequestparams)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a request interceptor in config section and then pass an extra param to every request, like Auth token etc.

https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#addrequestinterceptor

Another simpler way is to add default params as described here by resangular api.

https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#setdefaultrequestparams